# Fatal error : unexpectedly found nil - number of row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, fatal-error

My UITableViewController was working fine until recently when it crashed at the tableview's numberOfRowsInSection upon the initial loading.

[image]

The datasource is fetched in the following method:

```
  func reloadTheTable()
  {
    datasource = PlaceDataController.fetchAllPlaces()
    tableView?.reloadData()
  }
```

The method in my Realm model is:

```
class func fetchAllPlaces() -> Results<PlaceItem>!
  {
    do
    {
      let realm = try Realm()
      return realm.objects(PlaceItem)
    }
    catch
    {
      return nil
    }
  }
```

How do I debug this error? It was working fine before. Really puzzling why it's crashing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `datasource` is an implicitly unwrapped optional according to `fetchAllPlaces` return type.

First, `fetchAllPlaces`shouldn't return an  implicitly unwrapped optional since you know the value can be `nil`, replace it by :

```
class func fetchAllPlaces() -> Results<PlaceItem>?
{
    do
    {
        let realm = try Realm()
        return realm.objects(PlaceItem)
    }
    catch
    {
        return nil
    }  
}
```

Also, declare your `datasource` as optional.

Then replace your  `numberOfRowsInSection` method :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let dataSource = datasource {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: I agree, but all the code in your numberOfRowsInSection method can be replaced with a single line `return datasource?.count ?? 0`.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Lyndsey. Your suggestions worked! Appreciate it.

Comment: @LyndseyScott : You're totally right, i'm just used to this format for readability, and have a hard time changing ^^

Comment: I tend to use optional return type overtime when i know the function can return a nil value : this way it's easier to find issues in your code. I do the same for variables, the only time I use implicitly unwrapped variable is when i'm sure they will be initialized quite quickly and for sure (in viewDidLoad for example).